# Iterating Over s3 Buckets using Boto3 in Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I am attempting to iterate over all the buckets in a specific account and add all of the bucket names to a list so that I can apply bucket policies and logging to those buckets that I've stored in list.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    # print("hanlder:event")
    # print(event)
    # bucketDump()
    setBucketPolicy(bucketDump())


def bucketDump():
    ##This program lists all exsisting buckets within an aws account (Tommy's Personal Account)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_buckets()

    # Output the bucket names
    # print('Existing buckets:')

    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        if bucket is not None:
            buckets = []
            value = bucket["Name"]
            buckets.append(value)
           
        else: 
            break
    return buckets
            

    ##setting a bucket policy
def setBucketPolicy(buckets):
    print(buckets)
```

My issue is that it is only returning the last bucket, so when I call the function it only prints one single bucket. However if I take away the "return" and just print `print(bucket['Name'])`  I get a printed list of all the buckets but obviously that is not usable in a function. thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare buckets = [] outside of the for loop